# Converting array to char

Tags: array, convert

I'm trying to convert a char array to a char. i used this code

```
char code[4] = {'1','2','3','4'};

char strcode[4];



void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600);
}


void loop()
{
    memcpy(strcode, code, 4);
    Serial.println(strcode);
    Serial.println("done");
    delay(1000);
}
```

But for some reason when i read my serial monitor i get this:

```
1234
done
```

Why are there 2 squares behind it?  Am I doing it wrong?

EDIT: For some reason stackexchange doesn't show the 2 squares but there are 2 squares behind 1234

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C strings need to be NUL-terminated.

```
char strcode[5];

 ...

 ...
     ...
    strcode[4] = '\0';
     ...
```